# multilanguage youtube subtitle support

Tags: video, youtube, caption

i'm curious in finding an alternative for youtube video captions/subtitles. I wish to give open access to anyone to add subtitles in their native languages for videos posted on my site.

Do you have any idea about how can be this done? Do you have any ideas what tools to use? I'm good with PHP.

Comment: You can add Amara Youtube HTML5 transcription/translation widget to your own website using the steps here : https://github.com/pculture/unisubs/wiki/Widgetizer-Script---for-YouTube-and-HTML5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think I've finded the solution

http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_captions.html

wish me good luck

Answer (score 0):

Found the following steps useful in Transcribing and Translating Video subtitles/transcripts.
Took a few weeks work to get the whole thing working so it might save someone some time.

1) Use Amara.org (formerly known as universalsubtitles.org).
This site is used by TED.com, Mozilla, PBS etc to transcribe and translate their videos using crowd-sourcing from fans.

2) Transcription :
Note : Google uses Auto Speech Recognition to generate Captions from speech.
But auto translations can be good or bad or really funny so manual editing may be required.
Some videos may not show auto captions due to variety of documented reasons.

a) Google2Str tool allows downloading of "English Automatic Captions" in .srt format (though format is not correct)
b) Convert to proper .srt format using Jubler software.
c) Upload converted Transcription to Amara for the video.
d) Manually Correct the transcript and download.
e) Upload corrected transcript to youtube.

3) Translation :
Google also does Auto Translation from English Auto Captions to Specified Language from "Captions Menu".
If English Auto Captions are funny the Translated Auto Captions may be gibberish.
a) Upload English .srt subtitle file to Google Translator Toolkit.
b) Translate to Target language .srt file from English to Target Language.
c) Download .srt file.
d) Upload Translation to Amara for the video.
e) Manually Correct the tranlation and download.
f) Upload corrected transcript to youtube.

If you're not using youtube to host the videos you can skip the youtube related steps.

To view the youtube video with specific language use the following URL (requires uploaded translation) : http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEOID?version=3&start=300&end=500&autoplay=1&hl=en_US&rel=0&yt:cc=on&version=3&cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=hi

Note: Replace VIDEOID with specific code for your video.
Hope this helps someone out there.

Comment: You can add Amara Youtube HTML5 widget to your own website using the steps here : https://github.com/pculture/unisubs/wiki/Widgetizer-Script---for-YouTube-and-HTML5